# How to change menu entries in AppIndicator, when it is running?

Tags: unity, python, indicator, gtk3, pygi

There is a similar question at StackOverflow, but it didn't help me: [Changing items while running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852734/changing-items-while-running). I tried asking at StackOverflow, but people there where not too active: [How to change GTK menu in Unity Indicator Applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273020/how-to-change-gtk-menu-in-unity-indicator-applet).

The problem is, if I define the changing function outside of Gtk.main(), it would be never executed, and inside it would be executed just once. If I make an infinite loop inside, Gtk.main() would be never executed.
This is my code (modified standard example).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ind = appindicator.Indicator.new ("example-simple-client",
                                      "indicator-messages",
                         appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
    ind.set_status (appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    ind.set_attention_icon ("indicator-messages-new")

    menu = Gtk.Menu()
    menu_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    def add_item(menu, label):
        menu.append(MenuItem(label))
    menu.append(menu_quit)
    def quit_app(w):
        sys.exit(0)
    menu_quit.connect('activate', quit_app)
    menu_quit.show()
    ind.set_menu(menu)   
    Gtk.main()
```

Where do I put adding new menu items (or changing existing) in the code?
I am a real newbie in GUI programming...

Comment: How and when do you want to call `add_item()`? You should give a bit more information.

Comment: I want to call it, when user gets something in clipboard.

Comment: I think this is quite a broad question, actually, as the same applies to any GTK menus, not only AppIndicator, and even not only menus, but, actually, any  GTK widgets. I really need to get a hold on that, I think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has to use

```
GLib.timeout_add(10, handler_timeout)
```

inside the indicator code, where 10 - is 10 milliseconds, time between refreshing, and handler_timeout - function to be called at each refresh. Inside this function one can do all the needed stuff, like checking for clipboard changes and editing the menu.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I have similar issues and using GLib's timeout_add method gives me `Segmentation fault` error.

Comment: I can't really help, because I didn't get a `Segmentation fault` when used it... It just worked like a charm really.